# MySQL with JDBC: Broken character encoding in Timezone string

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a (locally hosted) MySQL server using the Java Connector. I am getting the exception:

```
The server time zone value 'Mitteleurop�ische Sommerzeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

As you can see, the timezone value is not transferred correctly, causing the connector to not understand the timezone. I have tried setting every possible setting to UTF-8 (`useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` in the JDBC URL, `character-set-server` is also set to `utf8`). What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please add the Connection string that you are using to connect to MySQL and also the Connector/J jar version that you are using, to be able to help you?

Comment: Connection string is `jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`. I added `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` to try and fix this problem, but it did not help. From what I understood these should not be needed.
Connector/J version is 6.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this is most likely caused not by the connection between the MySQL server and my application, but the communication between MySQL and the OS. Setting the timezone manually in the configuration and not letting it "figure it out" from the OS solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, MySQL server doesn't use UTF-8 by default. You must manually set attributes in my.cnf to look like these:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

These are possible locations of config file on Linux:
    /etc/my.cnf
    /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: default-character-set and character-set-server are already set to utf8. I set collaction-server to utf8_unicode_ci and the init-connect setting as well, the problem still persists.